# Adding scrollbars to QML widgets (Qt 5.9.3)

Tags: qt, scroll, qml, scrollbar

I need to add vertical scrolling to `TextEdit` and horizontal scrolling to `ListView` with displaying scrollbars if necessary. Both widgets have to fill the whole space provided by their parent layouts. How can I do that? Examples haven't helped me.

`ScrollableTextEdit`:

```
ColumnLayout {
    ...
    ScrollView {
        id: scroll_view
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        ScrollBar.horizontal.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOff
        ???
        Rectangle {
            border.color: 'gray'
            ???
            TextEdit {
                id: text_edit
                anchors.fill: parent
                textFormat: TextEdit.RichText
                wrapMode: TextEdit.Wrap
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`ScrollableListView`:

```
ColumnLayout {
    ...
    ScrollView {
        id: scroll_view
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        ScrollBar.vertical.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOff
        ???
        Rectangle {
            border.color: 'gray'
            ???
            ListView {
                id: list_view
                anchors.fill: parent
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many Item layers. The ScrollView should be the direct parent of the TextEdit. For the ListView, you can use the attached ScrollBar.horizontal property to create a scrollbar without using a ScrollView.

See example below

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    x: 0
    y: 0
    width: 600
    height: 200
    id: root

    RowLayout
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 20

        ColumnLayout
        {
            Label
            {
                text: "Example 1 (Vertical TextEdit)"
            }

            ScrollView
            {
                id: textEdit
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                clip: true
                TextEdit
                {
                    text: "A very\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery long text"
                    anchors.fill: parent
                }
            }
        }


        ColumnLayout
        {
            Label
            {
                text: "Example 2 (Horizontal ListView)"
            }

            ListView
            {
                id: listView
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                model: 10
                spacing: 10

                orientation: ListView.Horizontal
                ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar {}

                delegate: Rectangle {
                    border.width: 1
                    height: parent.height
                    width: 100
                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: index
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```